# Как в поле одного объекта записать List другого объекта и поле по id

Tags: java

Даны три класса: User, Region и Post.
Три текстовых файла, с соответствующими названиями, в которые заносятся через toString()  данные полей.

```
class Region(Long id, String name){}
        Region reg1 = new Region(1, "RU/");
        Region reg2 = new Region(2, "EU/");
    
    Region getById(Long id) {
        return region("из файла нужный");
            
class Post(Long id, String name){}
        Post post1 = new Post(1, "Статья1");
        Post post1 = new Post(2, "Статья2");
    
    Post getById(Long id) {
        return post ("из файла нужный");

class User(Long id, Region region, List<Post> post){
    public List<Post> getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(List<Post> post) {
        this.post = post;
    }

    public Region getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(Region region) {
        this.region = region;
    }
}
```

Вопрос собственно в том, я не понимаю, как, допустим вводить нового Usera, чтобы при создании указывать
new User(1, 1, 1); //первый "1"- id. второй "1"-номер листа?. третий "1" - id региона из файла
Не понимаю я, создавать мне новые методы или в конструкторе как прописывать, чтобы при вводе id у меня в текстовый файл с юзером записывались List post и Region region.
Надеюсь сжато ясно объяснил задачу, конечно, есть еще методы, которые в файл записывают и из файла читают, но думаю вопрос тут не в этом

Comment: Уточните, это какой язык?

Comment: Java, в метке указал

Answer (score 1):

Сообственно не можете понять потому что это не правильно. По принципам SOLID у вас класс самый обычный и он не должен считывать себя откуда либо. Посморите примеры в основном какието лодеры/сервисы/утилиты которые возвращают вам объекты. А сами они ни очем не подозревают откуда они взялись и зачем.

> Принцип единственной ответственности (англ. single-responsibility
> principle, SRP) — принцип ООП, обозначающий, что каждый объект должен
> иметь одну ответственность и эта ответственность должна быть полностью
> инкапсулирована в класс. Все его поведения должны быть направлены
> исключительно на обеспечение этой ответственности.

По собственно вопросу.

Делаете

```
class UserLoader {

  String fileName ...

  public UserLoader(...){...}

  public User loadUser(Long id, Region region) { ..... }
}
```

PS. Всё это верно если я конечно понял ваш вопрос. Прошу не хейтить ответ вполне редактируем